# PCRE: Find matching brace for code block

Tags: php, nested, pcre, codeblocks, curly-braces

Is there a way for PCRE regular expressions to count how many occurrences of a character it encounters (n), and to stop searching after it has found n occurrences of another character (specifically `{` and `}`).

This is to grab code blocks (which may or may not have code blocks nested inside them).

If it makes it simpler, the input will be a single-line string, with the only characters other than braces are digits, colons and commas. The input must pass the following criteria before code blocks are even attempted to be extracted:

```
$regex = '%^(\\d|\\:|\\{|\\}|,)*$%';
```

All braces will have a matching pair, and nested correctly.

I would like to know if this can be achieved before I start writing a script to check every character in the string and count each occurrence of a brace. Regular expressions would be much more memory friendly as these strings can be several kilobytes in size!

Thanks, mniz.

### Solution

[PCRE: Lazy and Greedy at the same time (Possessive Quantifiers)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344747/pcre-lazy-and-greedy-at-the-same-time-possessive-quantifiers/2353753#2353753)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pcre has [recursive patterns](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.recursive.php), so you can do something like this

```
$code_is_valid = preg_match('~^({ ( (?>[^{}]+) | (?1) )* })$~x', '{' . $code .'}');
```

the other thing, i don't think this will be faster or less memory consuming than simple counter, especially on large strings.

and this is how to find all (valid) codeblocks in a string

```
preg_match_all('~ { ( (?>[^{}]+) | (?R) )* } ~x', $input, $blocks);
print_r($blocks);
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I'm going to make both solutions, and benchmark / profile them to see which is more appropriate.
By the looks of things, I was wrong and was probably better off iterating over each character!

Comment: @user187291 What does ?> means ?

Answer (score 4):

This is exactly what regular expressions are *not* good for. It's the classic example.

You should just iterate over the string character by character, and keep a count of the nesting level.

Answer (score 0):

```
$regex='%^(\\d|\\:|\\{|\\}|,){0,25)$%';
preg_match($regex,$target,$matches);
```

where: 25 on first line indicates maximum number of occurrences. then check:

```
$n=count($matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible since the language you are describing is not a [regular language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language).

Use a parser instead.