# Match a PHP class with a Regular Expression

Tags: php, regex, class

I wanna catch Php classes from a file:

```
class a {
   function test() { }
}

class b extends a {
   function test() { }
}
```

and the result matches must be

```
class a {
   function test() { }
}
```

and

```
class b extends a {
   function test() { }
}
```

Comment: Consider: `/* class None {} */ class C {}` and/or `class D { $a="class None{}}"; }`. In other words: this is not possible using regex, you'll need a parser.

Comment: @Bart: This is possible to do with a regex. But if you can't imagine how it should go, better not even try.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

regexps are poor at parsing programming languages' grammars. Consider tokenizer functions instead. e.g. http://php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php
see also this http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/Zend_Reflection/Zend_Reflection_File.html

Comment: @Wiliam, an example of `token_get_all($source)` can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217839/regex-removing-methods-from-code

Comment: @Bart K., it's for an small C# app to separe my classes into individual files. This is a good response, but not the one I'm searching, the last regex I posted here as answer works for me but I'm going to mark your response as the good one, thanks.

Comment: @Wiliam, note that it's not my answer but `stereofrog`'s.

Answer (score 1):

A single regex won't do this.  PHP is a more complex language than regex (insert something about context-free and regular grammars here).  It'll drive you crazy to even try, unless you alter your source code to make it easier for the regex to match.

Answer (score 0):

The next Regex worked for now:

```
^(?:(public|protected|private|abstract)\s+)?class\s+([a-z0-9_]+)(?:\s+extends\s+([a-z0-9_]+))?(?:\s+implements\s+([a-z0-9_]+))?.+?{.+?^}
```

Needs:

```
case insensitive | ^$ match at line breaks | dot matches new lines
```

This only works if "class" and the last "}" don't have indent.

Comment: `.+?` will make it fail if there's a string or comment with an `}` inside of it. At the very last, make it greedy or add something like `\s*$` to the end of your regex.

Comment: This is not really correct, for instance it doesn't capture final classes and classes that implement more than one interface.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you should use:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php

Answer (score 0):

Use [`token_get_all`](http://php.net/token_get_all) to get the array of [language tokens](http://php.net/tokens) of the PHP code. Then iterate it and look for a token with the value of *T_CLASS* that represents the `class` key word (this does not take abstract classes or the visibility into account). The next *T_STRING* token is the name of the class. Then look for the next plain token that’s value is `{`, increase a counter for the block depth and decrease it with every plain `}` token until visited the same amount of closing braces as opening braces (your counter is then 0). Then you have walked the whole class declaration.

Answer (score 0):

here the official way:

```
^[a-zA-Z_\x80-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x80-\xff]*$
```

from https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

so it would be:

```
class[\s]{1,}[a-zA-Z_\x80-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x80-\xff]*
```